# Button keeps old state of Bloc in Flutter

Tags: flutter, state, bloc

I have a question regarding updating state in Bloc state management. When updating my state directly inside Bloc file my states are ok when I'm using them on widgets. Everything is changing in correct way. But when I want to use actual state inside onPressed function of button, I have not updated state (have "False" -> should be "true"). Please see below some code for better understanding:

I have code for button like this (main page file):

```
CupertinoButton(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      onPressed: () {
                        context.read<CreateUserCredentialsBloc>().add(
                            CreateUserCredentialsEvent.createButtonPressed(context));
                        print(state.authorizationSuccess);
```

then, by pressing button I call this which is inside bloc file:

```
createButtonPressed: (event) async{
          validate(event, emit);//validate registration function
          if(state.authType == 'register' && state.userNameValidation == true && state.userPasswordValidation == true){
            final result = await useCase(
                UserParams(
                userPassword: state.userPassword,
                userLogin: state.userLogin,
                userSurName: state.userSurName,
                userName: state.userName));
            result.fold((failure){
              // emit(state.copyWith(authSuccess: false));
              MySnackBar().showSnackBar('Coś poszło nie tak.\nSpróbuj ponownie.', event.context);
            }, (result){
              emit(state.copyWith(authorizationSuccess: true, authType: 'login'));
              return MySnackBar().showSnackBar('Rejstracja przebiegła pomyślnie.\nZaloguj się.', event.context);
              // emit(CreateUserCredentialsState.initial());
            });
          }else{
            null;
          }
          },
```

As You can see, when result is successful I change the status of authorization to 'true':

```
emit(state.copyWith(authorizationSuccess: true, authType: 'login'));
```

But, when I print state of authorisation inside Cupertino button it is still "false".
If You have any ideas please let me know.
Thanks.